# javascript for loop function to merge two new arrays.

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

As part of my learning exercise, I am trying to create a function with a For loop. The function returns a new array variable merges and matches the index value of both array `musicians` and `instruments`.
So the expected return should be string:
"John Lennon Plays Guitar"

Here is my attempt, but I keep failing to get the return:

```
var musicians = ["John Lennon", "Paul McCartney", "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr"]
var instruments = ["Guitar", "Bass Guitar", "Lead Guitar", "Drums"]

  function theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments) {      

    for (let i=0; i<musicians.length; i++) {

      var newMusicians = musicians[i]
      var newInstruments = instruments[i]
    }

    console.log(newMusicians[i] + "plays" + instruments[i])
  }
```

Comment: `console.log` should be inside the `for` loop

Comment: Put the console.log inside the for loop. Also, there's no need for those variables.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting your variables on every iteration of the loop. You need to create an empty array and fill it (and then return it):

```js
var musicians = ["John Lennon", "Paul McCartney", "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr"]
var instruments = ["Guitar", "Bass Guitar", "Lead Guitar", "Drums"]

function theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments) {
  var combinations = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < musicians.length; i++) {
    combinations.push(musicians[i] + ' plays ' + instruments[i]);
  }

  return combinations;
}

console.log(theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments));
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues are there.

The function need to return the merged array.
Secondly the function was never called. You may not need to again create a variable inside the loop

```js
var musicians = ["John Lennon", "Paul McCartney", "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr"]
var instruments = ["Guitar", "Bass Guitar", "Lead Guitar", "Drums"]


function theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments) {
  var mergedArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < musicians.length; i++) {
    mergedArray.push(musicians[i] + " plays " + instruments[i])

  }
  return mergedArray;

}
console.log(theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Few observations as per your code :**

- Add **`;`** after each statement inside for loop for good coding practices.
- put `console.log` statement inside `for` loop as it will print the values iterates inside for loop.
- Instead of `newMusicians[i]` use `newMusicians` in console.log.

```js
var musicians = ["John Lennon", "Paul McCartney", "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr"]
var instruments = ["Guitar", "Bass Guitar", "Lead Guitar", "Drums"]

  function theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments) {      

    for (let i = 0; i < musicians.length; i++) {
      var newMusicians = musicians[i];
      var newInstruments = instruments[i];
      console.log(newMusicians + " plays " + instruments[i]);
    }
  }
  
 theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments);
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You need to put `console.log` inside the `for` loop.
2. Also, `console.log(newMusicians + " plays " + instruments[i])`

`newMusicians` instead of `newMusicians[i]` in while logging

```js
var musicians = ["John Lennon", "Paul McCartney", "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr"]
var instruments = ["Guitar", "Bass Guitar", "Lead Guitar", "Drums"]

  function theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments) {      

    for (let i=0; i<musicians.length; i++) {

      var newMusicians = musicians[i];
      var newInstruments = instruments[i];
      console.log(newMusicians + " plays " + instruments[i])
    }

    
  }
  
  theBeatlesPlay(musicians, instruments);
```